# Microsoft Speech Recognizer 6.1 Training Files

Tags: c#, speech-recognition, sapi

I am developing a Speech Application in C#. The speech recognition stuff is working fine with SAPI 5.1 on Windows XP. But I now have Microsoft Speech Recognizer v 6.1 on my machine that came with Office 2003. No matter how much training I do, I see that the speech files (the .dat files under MSASR) are not getting updated ( at least from the last modified time stamp) . Can someone please  let me know if there is any major change in how speech training works in Speech Recognizer v 6.1 when compared to v 5.1 ?

Thanks in advance.

UPDATE: Someone answered the question in the Microsoft Speech Forums. Here is the link to the reply. http://www.microsoft.com/communities/newsgroups/en-us/default.aspx?dg=microsoft.public.speech_tech.sdk&mid=53f6b970-3252-4ef5-91da-eaf20367c023&sloc=en-us

Comment: Link above is dead - try the following instead (seems to be the same question / answer on Google Groups): https://groups.google.com/group/microsoft.public.speech_tech.sdk/browse_thread/thread/916f08bf66eb3d/cbe9830a860b81f3?lnk=gst

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you are looking in the right place? Check the registry under HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Speech\RecoProfiles
for info about user profiles and training data. I'm on Vista, control panel indicates that it is version 8.0. I see the training files updating.

This MSDN reference has details of registry settings http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms717036(VS.85).aspx